# Alias for singleton object

Tags: objective-c, singleton, alias

I have this singleton class code where I keep calling stuff like this:

```
[[Core sharedCore] variantPrice:@"variant_no"];
```

How can I make an alias (that Xcode will also understand) that makes it like this:

```
[Core variantPrice:@"variant_no"]
```

Comment: You could do: `+(void)variantPrice:(NSString *)variant{[[Core sharedCore] variantPrice:variant];}`. In other words, using a method class that will call itself the singleton method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the below statement anywhere and use _gCore wherever required:

```
# define _gCore [Core sharedCore]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I needed. I just replaced that statement 1074 times and it instantly passed all my tests :). Thanks again!

Comment: This *may* solve the problem, but using [macros like this is a sure code smell](http://qualitycoding.org/preprocessor/). If you're *really* accessing your singleton enough times to warrant a shortcut – you probably need to restructure how your code works in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You write a class method

```
+ (void)variantPrice
```

which calls

```
[[self sharedCore] variantPrice]
```

Comment: I think I stated my question wrong, sorry. What I want to achieve is a simplified statement of the (static) singleton `Core` so that every time I call something on my singleton I can simplify the `[Core sharedCore]` part (that repeats a lot throughout my app, to just become `Core` or `sharedCore` if the `Core` name would conflict. I'm not sure but maybe that something like compiler hinting?